# FastApi return relational data from sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi

Hi all Im trying to create an app for tests. One *test config* **has many** *test cases*

Data Is saved correctly but when I'm trying to get this data I get an empty list like this

```py
@router.get("/cases_conf/", response_model=list[ConfigItem])
    def read_cases_by_config(cases: List, db: orm.Session = Depends(services.get_db)):
        cases = services.get_test_by_config(db=db)
        return cases
```

returns

```json
{
 "spec_name": "string",
 "test_cases": []
}
```

This is my model and my pydantic schema
**models**
There is a relation one to many for config -> testcase

```py
class ConfigTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'ConfigTable'
    id = sql.Column(sql.Integer, primary_key=True)
    spec_name = sql.Column(sql.String(30), nullable=True)
    test_cases = relationship("TestCase", back_populates="owner")
    date_created = sql.Column(sql.DateTime, default=dt.datetime.utcnow)
    date_last_updated = sql.Column(sql.DateTime, default=dt.datetime.utcnow)


class TestCase(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'TestCase'
    id = sql.Column(sql.Integer, primary_key=True)
    TaskName = sql.Column(sql.String(100), nullable=True)

    config_id = sql.Column(Integer, ForeignKey("ConfigTable.id"), nullable=True)
    owner = relationship("ConfigTable", back_populates="test_cases")

    date_created = sql.Column(sql.DateTime, default=dt.datetime.utcnow)
    date_last_updated = sql.Column(sql.DateTime, default=dt.datetime.utcnow)
```

**schemas**

```py
class TestCase(pydantic.BaseModel):
    TaskName: Optional[str] = None

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

class CaseItem(TestCase):
    config_id: Optional[int] = None

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

class CaseConfig(pydantic.BaseModel):
    spec_name: str


class ConfigItem(CaseConfig):
    test_cases: list[TestCase] = []

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

In other words, how can I get response like this

```json
{
   "spec_name":"string",
   "test_cases":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "TaskName":"test1"
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "TaskName":"test2"
      }
   ]
}
```

**read_cases_by_config** executes

```
return db.query(models.ConfigTable).all()
```

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring your `response_model` as `list[ConfigItem]`, but in your desired example is just `ConfigItem`, so you need to change that. Depending on what `services.get_test_by_config` returns, you might need other changes. If it is a list of `TestCase`s, it should be something like

```py
@router.get("/cases_conf/", response_model=ConfigItem)
def read_cases_by_config(db: orm.Session = Depends(services.get_db)):
    cases = services.get_test_by_config(db=db)
    return {
        "spec_name": "",
        "test_cases": cases,
    }
```

Comment: Okay, I've changed to your code now. There is an issue tho. I have only one item in test_cases. I got all the keys with value of null despite the database being full

Comment: What does `services.get_test_by_config` look like? What does it return?

Comment: Iv edited my question, look at the bottom.  Let's say that there are 3 config instances. All of them have 5 different test related points. I would imagine that this returns that.